# Response headers missing after Nginx

Tags: node.js, express, nginx, cors

I set up a Nginx reverse proxy on top of nodejs/express Rest API.

On the Nodejs rest api the there are CORS headers set.
And if I make a curl call directly to this api I get back the following response (with Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://example.fun ...)

```
curl 'http://auth_auth-node:3005/api/v1/auth/signin' \
   -IL \
   -X 'POST' \
   -H 'Connection: keep-alive' \
   -H 'Content-Length: 0' \
   -H 'sec-ch-ua: "Google Chrome";v="89", "Chromium";v="89", ";Not A Brand";v="99"' \
   -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 11_2_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/89.0.4389.114 Safari/537.36' \
   -H 'sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0' \
   -H 'authorization: Basic MTIzMTIzMTIzOjEyMzEyMzEyMzEyMw==' \
   -H 'Accept: */*' \
   -H 'Origin: https://example.fun' \
   -H 'Sec-Fetch-Site: same-site' \
   -H 'Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors' \
   -H 'Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty' \
   -H 'Referer: https://example.fun/' \
   -H 'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9,sl;q=0.8' \
   -H 'Cookie: G_ENABLED_IDPS=google'
   
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
X-Powered-By: Express
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://example.fun
Vary: Origin
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 35
ETag: W/"23-2KCO139FgVvJW0SbnMBTOug2br4"
Date: Mon, 12 Apr 2021 18:52:38 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
Keep-Alive: timeout=5
```

I can't figure out why this headers are missing after a call to nginx (as seen below)

```
curl 'https://api.example.fun/api/v1/auth/signin' \
    -IL \
    -X 'POST' \
    -H 'Connection: keep-alive' \
    -H 'Content-Length: 0' \
    -H 'sec-ch-ua: "Google Chrome";v="89", "Chromium";v="89", ";Not A Brand";v="99"' \
    -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 11_2_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/89.0.4389.114 Safari/537.36' \
    -H 'sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0' \
    -H 'authorization: Basic MTIzMTIzMTIzOjEyMzEyMzEyMzEyMw==' \
    -H 'Accept: */*' \
    -H 'Origin: https://example.fun' \
    -H 'Sec-Fetch-Site: same-site' \
    -H 'Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors' \
    -H 'Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty' \
    -H 'Referer: https://example.fun/' \
    -H 'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9,sl;q=0.8' \
    -H 'Cookie: G_ENABLED_IDPS=google'
    
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Server: nginx/1.19.9
Date: Mon, 12 Apr 2021 18:33:29 GMT
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 40
Connection: keep-alive
```

Nginx configuration:

```
    upstream auth-node { 
        server auth_auth-node:3005; 
    }
    server {
    access_log /var/log/nginx/auth_node.log main; # Each API may also log to a separate file

    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name api.example.fun;

    # TLS config
    ssl_certificate      /etc/certs/domain.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key  /etc/certs/domain.key;
    ssl_session_cache    shared:SSL:20m;
    ssl_session_timeout  15m;
    ssl_ciphers          HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
    ssl_protocols        TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://auth-node; # proxy to the server
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
    }
    error_page 404 = @400;         # Invalid paths are treated as bad requests
    proxy_intercept_errors on;     # Do not send backend errors to the client
    include /etc/nginx/api_json_errors.conf;  # API client friendly JSON error responses
    default_type application/json; 
    }
```

Comment: Try to add `proxy_pass_request_headers      on;` to the location block.

Comment: @Molda thanks, tried. It did not make any change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually figured it out.

In HTTP part of nginx.conf I had `include /etc/nginx/api_json_errors.conf;`
After commenting it out the headers are there.